# Can a class implement two interfaces at the same time?

Tags: c#

I tried doing something like this:

```
class Student: IPersonalDetails: IOtherDetails
{
      //Code
}
```

It gives error. Why I can't implement two interfaces?

Comment: separate the interface names with a comma (,)

Comment: I always feel bad when trivial questions like this get upvotes and legitimate computer-science questions do not get upvotes it deserve. ...  :(

Comment: @Srinivas: Please downgrade it.

Comment: @RPK my votes are over for today :)

Comment: @Srinivas: A question is "trivial" only if you already know the answer; this question was not trivial to RPK; it is a perfectly reasonable question that is within the scope of specific technical programming questions. "Legitimate computer science" questions should not be posted to StackOverflow at all; StackOverflow is for questions about *programming computers*. **Computer science is not the same thing as programming**. "Legitimate computer science questions" should be posted to cstheory.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @Eric Lippert Though my wording may not be accurate,since english is not my mother tongue,I meant in the sense of programming questions.I still feel it is a trivial question!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use a comma between the interface types, e.g.

```
class Student: IPersonalDetails, IOtherDetails
{
      //Code
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Change it to

```
class Student: IPersonalDetails, IOtherDetails
{
  //Code
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Yes it can, have a deep look at your syntax.

Comment: for the one who downvoted. imho, pointing to the right direction is most of the time more helpful than the right answer itself. Because using his own brain is more excercise than using the other's brain.

Answer (score 1):

Yes! You definitely can. You can even implement more than 2. I am not sure if there is a limit on how many interfaces you can implement at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, a class can *definitely* implement more than one interface. After all, that is the *whole point* of interfaces.

Take a look at the error message you are getting. It is *not* telling you that a class cannot implement more than one interface. It is telling you that have a syntax error.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, or like this which of course targets completely different design goal and you could say that in fact it's still only one interface due to polymorphic nature of inheritance, but still:

```
public interface IEntity 
{
    void DoTask();
}

public interface IExtendedTaskEntity : IEntity
{
    void DoExtendedTask();
}

public class ConcreteEntity : IExtendedTaskEntity 
{

    #region IExtendedTaskEntity Members

    public void DoExtendedTask()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    #endregion

    #region IEntity Members

    public void DoTask()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    #endregion
}
```